# How to remove one commit between commits which is already pushed?

Tags: git

Suppose I have 3 commits pushed in the remote branch **dev** in descending order by date.

```
commit 3
commit 2
commit 1
```

How can I remove **commit 2** while preserving **commit 3** and  **commit 1** ? Or is there any alternative way to do that ?

Comment: simply revert that commit

`git revert commit-2`

Comment: What does "remove" mean? Undo its effects, or change the past so the commit appears never to have existed?

Comment: To literally *remove* commit 2, you must also remove commit 3. Commit 1 is not affected since it occurs before the "bad" commit, but all subsequent commits must be stripped in order to strip out any particular commit. It's therefore often wiser not to remove anything at all, but rather just add a fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `git rebase -i commit-1` and choosing to `drop commit-2`.

However, doing so is not recommended if it's already been pushed to the remote, since someone else might have already pulled your changes and it'll mess up their code-base.

So, as someone else pointed out in the comments, it's better to use `git revert commit-2` which will create a new `commit-4` which is the exact opposite of `commit-2`

Comment: Can you please clarify "new commit-4 which is the exact opposite of commit-2"?

Comment: @AshishKafle I mean't that the `commit-4` will be the same as applying the reverse diff of `commit-2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can revert a particular commit with

```
git revert <commit_hash> (example: hashcode of commit-2)
```

<commit_hash>  is the code you can find from the git-branch history or with the (git log) command

- Git -> you project -> branch in which you made commits -> History of the branch -> Copy (SHA) this is your commit hashcode

Note: if you made changes in the same file in commit-2 and commit-3. Maybe there will be some conflict. you need to resolve it.